# Laravel - Use Request to create in different model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, request

I use a request class to create a Project.

```
public function store(ProjectFormRequest $request)
{
  return \Redirect::route('projects');
}
```

Each Project should contain n images. How can I safe the images, which are in the $request to the database coming from a Form but IN the Request class?

Normally I would foreach the form input field, upload the images, save the images and attach / sync it with the Project model (one to many relationship; one Project has many images; one image has one Project).

How can I do that in the Request class? Or do I need to do it in the controller store() method?

Comment: FormRequest classes are used for validation, you shouldn't be saving anything here, this is a job for the controller. You seem to  be aware of this already, why do you want to do this in your FormRequest.

Comment: I just thought that I might be possible or useful. If not I will close my question as you answered it properly. :)

Comment: @Marek123 craig is right here Marek, your request class should represent the structure of the request itself and the rules to validate it, it shouldn't be the place the request is handled. You are right to type hint the request in a controller method and handle it there.